# Tree cutting problem : removing array list element without breaking order

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a problem given to me which it couldn't solved efficiently for all possible cases. the problem was, given X tree on a street and one tree need to be cut in a manner that remaining tree should be sorted in non descending order of height. determine number of ways tree can be cut under this condition.
X is an Integer with range 1 to 200 and each element value in array range from 1 to 1000 and can have duplicates.

Approach i took was comparing each array element to element on its left and right and updating counter if element on its left is small and element on its right is bigger. if its last or first element, it can only be remove if element next to it or element before it is bigger.

does it the correct way to solve this problem or should it be converted to one of data structure problem for an efficient solution ?

Comment: Yes, what you are thinking is correct. Is this problem available on any of the online judging websites like HackerRank or LeetCode? If so you can check the correctness of your program on one of them.

Comment: thanks Andrew but I couldn't find this problem on hackerRank or elsewhere

Comment: Where did you find this problem?